# I'm trying to load BERT "tfbert-large-uncased" but i got an error "Can't load config.json file"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I'm trying to load the pre-train BERT model but I'm getting an error while loading tokenized it says config.json is not found.
If anyone knows how to solve these issues please help me

Model and path configure

```
model_name = 'bert_v13'

data_dir = Path('../input/commonlitreadabilityprize/')
train_file = data_dir / 'train.csv'
test_file = data_dir / 'test.csv'
sample_file = data_dir / 'sample_submission.csv'

build_dir = Path('./build/')
output_dir = build_dir / model_name

trn_encode_file = output_dir / 'trn.enc.joblib'
val_predict_file = output_dir / f'{model_name}.val.txt'

submission_file = 'submission.csv'

pretrained_dir = '../tmp/input/tfbert-large-uncased'

id_col = 'id'
target_col = 'target'
text_col = 'excerpt'

max_len = 205
n_fold = 5
n_est = 2
n_stop = 2
batch_size = 8
seed = 42
```

Load Tokenizer and Model

```
# Tokenization using "Transformers"

# load tokenizer
def load_tokenizer():
    if not os.path.exists(pretrained_dir + '/vocab.txt'):
        Path(pretrained_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased")
        tokenizer.save_pretrained(pretrained_dir)
    else:
        print('loading the saved pretrained tokenizer')
        tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(pretrained_dir)
        
    model_config = BertConfig.from_pretrained(pretrained_dir)
    model_config.output_hidden_states = True
    return tokenizer, model_config

# load bert model
def load_bert(config):
    if not os.path.exists(pretrained_dir + '/tf_model.h5'):
        Path(pretrained_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased", config=config)
        bert_model.save_pretrained(pretrained_dir)
    else:
        print('loading the saved pretrained model')
        bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_dir, config=config)
    return bert_model
```

loading encoder

```
def bert_encode(texts, tokenizer, max_len=max_len):
    input_ids = []
    token_type_ids = []
    attention_mask = []
    
    for text in texts:
        token = tokenizer(text, max_lenght = max_len,truncation=True, padding='max_length',add_special_tokens = True)
        input_ids.append(token['input_ids'])
        
        token_type_ids.append(token['token_type_ids'])
        attention_mask.append(token['attention_mask'])
        
    return np.array(input_ids), np.array(token_type_ids),np.array(attention_mask)
```

this function gives an error

```
tokenizer, bert_cofig = load_tokenizer()

X = bert_encode(trn[text_col].values, tokenizer, 
                max_len=max_len)
X_tst = bert_encode(tst[text_col].values, tokenizer, 
                    max_len = max_len)
y = trn[target_col].values

print(X[0].shape, X_tst[0].shape, y.shape)
```

## Error

**file ../tmp/input/tfbert-large-uncased/config.json not found**

Comment: Add config.json to the tokenizer directory with only the "missing" configuration: `"model_type": "bert"`. Thanks!